# ACF and post object id failing to show proper content

Tags: php, wordpress, object, post, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) to allow a user to select from a list of pages that will then show a Title, Excerpt and Link for the respective pages.

For some reason this is pulling the excerpt of the current post instead of the related post id. The title and permalink word as desired. I'd love some help.

Thanks,
Jeffrey

```
<?php

/*
// Adding our custom content output
/*
*  Loop through post objects (assuming this is a multi-select field) ( don't setup postdata )
 *  Using this method, the $post object is never changed so all functions need a second parameter of the post ID in question.
*/

add_action( 'genesis_entry_content', 'genesis_project_list', 10, 2 );
add_action( 'genesis_post_content', 'genesis_project_list', 10, 2 );

// The Custom Content output function
function genesis_project_list() { 
$post_objects = get_field('acf_selected_projects');

if( $post_objects ): ?>
<ul style="list-style:none;">
<?php foreach( $post_objects as $post_object): ?>
    <li style="list-style:none;">
        <h3><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post_object->ID); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($post_object->ID); ?></a></h3>
        <span><?php echo get_the_excerpt($post_object->ID); ?></span>  
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post_object->ID); ?>">Read more...</a>

    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif;

}
genesis();
```

Comment: Please post `get_the_excerpt()` function's code, as it may be where something goes wrong, code above seems to look right.

Comment: Just found out that `get_the_excerpt()` is a built-in Wordpress function, I did wrongly assume it was a part of your site))

Comment: @mik-t Yes it is core function. I still don't understand why my original code wouldn't work. Happily though Jared had an alternative solution.

Comment: I'm pretty sure something goes wrong on the Wordpress side, somewhere inside `get_the_excerpt()`, also it seems that thus function is being deprecated (at least in the source code), see here: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/dfaa89d8531a3e34ec6c19b72f01e95ea3527fa0/wp-includes/post-template.php#L353

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `get_the_excerpt()` accepts an argument, so you can't pass `$post_object->ID` to get that post's excerpt. You'll have to write your own custom function for creating an excerpt. Here's some sample code I've used before (add this to your functions.php):

```
function custom_excerpt($str,$length=40,$append='...'){
    $pieces=explode(' ',strip_tags($str));
    $excerpt=implode(' ',array_slice($pieces,0,$length));
    if(count($pieces)>$length)
        $excerpt.=$append;
    return $excerpt;
}
```

And then in your template:

```
<span><?php echo custom_excerpt($post_object->post_content); ?></span>
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank You! 
Just to satisfy my curiosity, is it possible there was a simpler way to do this without adding code to functions.php? I ask this because it was working earlier for me and I didn't have anything more than getting the excerpt.

Comment: Try just putting this in your template then: `<span><?php echo implode(' ',array_slice(explode(' ',strip_tags($post_object->post_content)),0,40)).'...';?></span>`

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to choose door #1. :)